# How to make button to look as label?

Tags: html, css

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/raep4jeg/2/)

```
.TitleBtn
{
 border: none;
 background:none;
}
```

Click on the button and check. It ll show a blue border around it. I think it's input type buton's behaviour. I want to remove it. How to do it??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding this css to the button:

```
outline: none;
```

Your overall css would be:

```
.TitleBtn
{
 border: none;
 background:none;
 outline: none;
}
```